# Flutter) Android Setting Error " error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>. "

Tags: android, flutter

I'm going to use flutter_downloader to download the file.
For that, AndroidManifest.xml added the following code as instructed.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com......">
    <!-- flutter_downloader -->
    <provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    </application>
    .
    . 
    .
    .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader
This official site tells you to insert the following code into AndroidManifest.xml for Android use: provider ... /provider
However, after doing this, the following error is printed when building.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
       > Android resource linking failed
         /Users/home_1/Desktop/Projects/code/app/matching_project_rev2/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.
```

Is there a wrong location to add the code?

Comment: Yeah, `<provider>`s have to go in between the `<application>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

try this,its an example from their official repo, update as your need

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="vn.hunghd.example">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="Flutter Downloader"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <!-- Begin FlutterDownloader customization -->
        <!-- disable default Initializer -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>

        <!-- declare customized Initializer -->
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="5" />
        </provider>
        <!-- End FlutterDownloader customization -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.NOTIFICATION_ICON"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_flutter" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```